# What is the WPF browser application type project?

Tags: wpf

When should one use the WPF browser application? What is the utility of this project type? When should a developer use this?

Comment: I have never used this part of visual C#. I ordered a book on it to day, but was sitting at the office looking at example in Visual Studio and was wondering what the best sights would be to find examples on such programs.

Comment: This question is quite old and predates Microsoft Edge, does Edge support this?

Comment: XBAP (i.e. a WPF browser app) [only works with Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24100526/145173).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

XBAP applications (if that is what you are refering to) require the client to have the .NET framework installed (as opposed to Silverlight that only requires the Silverlight plug-in)

This allows XBAP applications to use the entire functionality of the .NET framework which is much broader than Silverlight.

Comment: You didn't answer his question: What is WPF browser application type project

Comment: I answered by not just reading the title but also by looking at the remainder of the question. I figured Thomas wanted to know what this type of project is useful for/what it is. Also, he ticked this answer as the answer to his question. I am afraid the English in the question is a bit broken. So I might be wrong.

Comment: I think you and @DanielMay have both provided information that is both helpful and relevant to the question, but Daniel does a better job of answering the original question, your answer does however provide information that adds on to Daniel's answer, but I don't believe it's a complete answer on it's own.

Answer (score 25):

A WPF Browser application is an app that runs in-browser as an XBAP (Xaml Browser Application).

You can find a little more information on the uses and reasons to use XBAPs [here](http://www.xbap.org/).

[This thread on MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en/wpf/thread/8bdff32d-6666-457c-8788-41b2c314bba1/) might help also.

Answer (score 3):

XBAP applications also may or may not have full trust and features depending on how you set it up and deploy it to the end users.  An advantage to an XBAP is that your users will always use the latest version that you publish, say to a website.

Answer (score 3):

**WPF** is Windows Presentation Foundation that creates the UI for Windows desktop applications (normally).

The **WPF Browser App** is similar to Java applets which uses a browser plugin to run the applet. In Microsoft case, a .Net Framework support plugin is what is used at the client side. i.e. web browser.

As a side note, xbap plugins and similar risky approaches are not supported in Google Chrome or Edge anymore. Therefore, it's good to avoid or unlearn developing in WPF browser apps.