# Is it possible to write internet browser available content by WPF?

Tags: asp.net, .net, wpf, wcf

I know that you can use ASP.NET to do that stuff but: Is it possible to write internet browser available content(website) by WPF or WCF?

Exacly I mean write CRM by WPF to which you can log by browser and use it by browser.

Comment: I assume you mean without Silverlight?

Comment: @lc. Oh I didn't think about it! Is Silverlight a good idea in this case. This would be simple CRM with cloud stored data, mostly strings. Thank you FOR POINTING it, it's seems genius.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't write an application with WPF and then run it in a browser.

You can use [XBAP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970060%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to create a browser application that can use the benefits of the .NET framework and all the things you can do in a WPF application.

Comment: Thank you! Could you please refer to lc. comment to OP, please : _

Comment: @Yoda You can indeed use `Silverlight`, but you can do more with `XBAP`. `XBAP` uses the .NET framework, whereas `Silverlight` uses the Silverlight plugin. [See here.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4782492/2478357)

Comment: -1. You have suggested the OP to use a completely inappropriate technology for his requirement. Please delete your answer immediately. The OP needs a `Web` application capable of serving PCs, mobile devices, and other Web-enabled devices. XBAP is a Windows-only technology and it is NOT a Web technology. It does not produce HTML and it does not work in mobile devices.

Comment: @HighCore The OP never asked that it should produce HTML or capable of running on a lot of different platforms. And I quote the site I linked: `Like Web applications, XBAPs can be deployed to a Web server and started from Internet Explorer or Firefox.` and `You deploy XBAPs to a Web server,...`. And I never said that it is a web technology. I answered the question the OP asked, so I don't understand your downvote. And I certainly won't delete my answer, as I think it answers the OP's question.